# Java - convert an epoch value into a Date based off timezone?

Tags: java, date, calendar, timezone, zoneddatetime

I have the following 3 fields in my `Appointment` entity:

```
private Long epochTime;
private String timezone;
private Calendar localAppointmentTime;
```

the timezone would be e.g. `America/New_York`

If the epochTime (i.e. UTC) value for the Appointment was e.g `1649075419` then I would want `localAppointmentTime` to be the epoch value but in the `America/New_York` timezone.

What is the best way to do so?

I have been trying to do the conversions as follows but not getting the results expected:

```
      // create calendar from epoch
      Long startdateEpochMilis = appointment.getEventEpochStartDateTime();
      Date startDate = new Date(startdateEpochMilis);
      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      calendar.setTime(startDate);

      LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(calendarToString(calendar),
              DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT));

      // set to match timezone selected by user
      ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of(appointment.getTimezone()));
      ZonedDateTime convertedZonedDateTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of(appointment.getTimezone()));

      Date convertedStartDate = Date.from(convertedZonedDateTime.toInstant());
      
      
    private static String calendarToString(Calendar calendar) {
    return dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
  }
```

Comment: The terrible `Date`/`Calendar` classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: You don't need three fields, and you should avoid storing redundant data. Use one `ZonedDateTime` field and derive epoch seconds and time zone from it on the fly when needed (may even derive a `Calendar` should you need one for a legacy API).

Comment: @OleV.V. No, this is for appointments. So we do need separate fields, not `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: @BasilBourque Right, thanks, then we need a.`LocalDateTime` and a `ZoneId`, still no epoch second, we can't even be sure what the right value would be.

Comment: @OleV.V. No, I cannot see a solution for this Question. First we have a faulty design, secondly a poor description of that design, and thirdly no sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems in your code, mainly

- the fact that an `Appointment`'s `epochTime` seems to be epoch **seconds** instead of epoch millis
- the mixture of an outdated API and an up-to-date one you are using

Use the `epochTime` to create an `Instant` and then use that to represent it human-readably for different time zones and do all that only with `java.time`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // use an example value (for epoch seconds)
    long epochTime = 1649075419L;
    // create a moment in time from the epoch seconds
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochTime);
    // create the desired time zones
    ZoneId americaNewYork = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
    ZoneId utc = ZoneId.of("UTC");
    // represent the Instant in different time zones
    ZonedDateTime utcZdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, utc);
    ZonedDateTime nyZdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, americaNewYork);
    // and print relevant values involved
    System.out.println("Epoch seconds:      " + instant.getEpochSecond());
    System.out.println("Epoch milliseconds: " + instant.toEpochMilli());
    System.out.println("UTC: " + utcZdt);
    System.out.println("NY:  " + nyZdt);
}
```

Output:

```
Epoch seconds:      1649075419
Epoch milliseconds: 1649075419000
UTC: 2022-04-04T12:30:19Z[UTC]
NY:  2022-04-04T08:30:19-04:00[America/New_York]
```

Comment: You could replace `ZoneId utc = …` with the predefined constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC). But really, you do not even need `utcZdt`, as you already have `instant`.

Comment: I made the example like this in order to show the relationship between epoch millis, seconds and the datetimes in different zones, but you are right, I could and maybe should have used the predefined constant.